# Angular2 listSearchPipe usage for arrays

Tags: angular, search, ngfor

```html
<div class="ui left icon input search-box">
  <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="{{ 'Search name' | translate }}" [(ngModel)]="searchText">
  <i class="search icon" style="left: auto;"></i>
</div>

<div>
  <div *ngFor="let k of fruits | listSearchPipe:'name':searchText | listSortPipe:'name';">
    <div class="iq-accordion-title iq-theme-title-admin"
         (click)="selectFruit(k)"
         [ngClass]="{'active': k.id === id}">
      <mat-icon class="iq-accordion-icon-left" svgIcon="cards-outline"></mat-icon>
      <span class="iq-accordion-span">{{k.name}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have the above code which executes a search based on name. My `Fruit` objects also have `tag` field which is a list of `string`.

Now, what I want to do is creating a search functionality for tag-based search as well. For example, when a tag is selected lets say "red", I want to show the objects which contain the tag "red". How can I achieve this with using something similar to the above code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you tried already ?

Comment: I have tried using ngIf inside the loop but it didn't seem right